# Use a macro in Excel without developer tab

Tags: excel, vba

I have created macros, e.g. form controls, by using VBA code in Excel. Now I want to send the Excel to colleagues and let them use it. Is it possible for them to use my macros without the developer tab? If possible, how?

Thanks,
A

Comment: Controls are not macros. If you have set up controls that call your macros, the user won't need the developer tab. If not, they can still use the macros dialog (alt+f8), assuming your workbook is not saved as an add-in.

Comment: Add in a button to the worksheet. You can assign a macro to the click event of the button